# Appending incoming query string from url to specific links on page

Tags: jquery, url, query-string, utm-tracking

I've been using the following script to append the query string of the incoming url to the links on a webpage, so they are carried through all pages the user goes within my site. The query string usually is utm tracking, but each value is unique and dynamicaly generated for each visitor.

The script used:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var getPageSubURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
jQuery('a').each(function() {
var currentURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
jQuery(this).attr('href', currentURL + '?' + getPageSubURL );
});
});
</script>
```

It works fine, but now I need it to apply **only to 3 specific links** on a page, since other links will have different parameters already hardcoded.

How should I edit this script to add this specific rule? Or is there a better way to do it?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just putting some css class (does not need to be an existing one) on those 3 anchors, if you know which exactly will be?

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="linkToModify"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#" class="linkToModify"></a>
<a href="#" class="linkToModify"></a>
<a href="#"></a>
```

and then your script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var getPageSubURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
jQuery('.linkToModify').each(function() {
var currentURL = jQuery(this).attr('href');
jQuery(this).attr('href', currentURL + '?' + getPageSubURL );
});
});
</script>
```